# Ostream << overloading confusion

Tags: c++, stream

When you're overloading the << operator for a class (pretend this is defined as a friend in SomeClass), why do you both take a reference to the ostream and return that ostream?

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& s, const SomeClass& c) {
    //whatever
    return s;
}
```

What benefit can returning the ostream be when it was already directly modifiable by reference? This seems redundant to me - though I'm sure it's not :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not redundant, but useful for chaining calls.  It's easier to see with functions like std::string::append, so I'll start with that:

```
std::string mystring("first");
mystring.append(" second");
mystring.append(" third");
```

can be rewritten as:

```
std::string mystring("first").append(" second").append(" third");
```

This is possible because .append() returns a reference to the string it modified, so we can keep adding .append(...) to the end.  The code correlating to what you are doing is changing from this:

```
std::cout << "first";
std::cout << " second";
std::cout << " third";
```

into this.  Since operator<< returns the stream, we can also chain these!

```
std::cout << "first" << " second" << " third";
```

see the similarity, and usefulness?

Comment: Thanks - everyone had similar answers, but I appreciated the example - it made it a lot more obvious how it works. :)

Answer (score 5):

It allows to "chain" output together. As in :

```
std::cout << someObj << someValue;
```

This is equivalent to something like :

```
operator<<(operator<<(std::cout, someObj), someValue);
```

Answer (score 4):

So that you can write chained-invocation  of `operator<<` as:

```
stream << s1 << s2 << s3 ;
```

If you don't return `ostream&`, then you cannot write it more than once.

You can think of that either as:

```
 operator<<(operator<<(operator<<(stream, s1), s2), s3);
```

Or as,

```
 ((stream << s1) << s2) << s3 ;
```

First `(stream << s1)` returns `stream&` on which you again invoke `<<` and it becomes `stream << s2` which returns `stream&` on which you again invoke `<<` and it becomes `stream << s3`.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, this is so linked output, like

cout << "this " << "is " << "a pen" << endl;

will still work.